# Missing Methods in .NET Framework Source Code

Tags: c#, .net

I've been browsing the .NET Framework source code this morning as I just wanted to check the behaviour of `Dipose()` on database connections.

However, viewing the .NET Framework source for SqlConnection (+ I've downloaded it as well), there is no method `Dispose()` defined in `SqlConnection`.

However, using dotPeek, I can see an implementation of `Dispose()` on SqlConnection

What am I missing?

Comment: Where do you see the SqlConnection that does nothing in the Dispose method? http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlConnection.cs,48932d2b804ed473

Comment: Hard to guess what you are looking at, but it can't be the Dispose() method.  The class doesn't re-implement IDisposable, it relies on the disposable pattern inherited from its base class.  [Look here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlConnection.cs,4b2c66bf1f6c12ee) instead.  Do keep in mind that the Reference Source is not complete for System.Data, parts of it were written in C++/CLI which is not included.

Comment: @Steve Where do you see a definition of `Dispose()` in that file? It just contains a `DisposeMe()` helper method, but not the `Dispose()` method. (It does contain `SqlDebugContext.Dispose()`, but not `SqlConnection.Dispose()`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you're really missing is that [`SqlConnection.cs`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlConnection.cs) defines `SqlConnection` as a `partial class`. This means other files can define member functions, including `Dispose()`. It's one of those other files that is defining the `Dispose()` member function.

Take a look at [`DbConnectionHelper.cs`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/ProviderBase/DbConnectionHelper.cs). This defines a class `CONNECTIONOBJECTNAME` in namespace `NAMESPACE`. Those would be replaced at build-time by the correct class name and namespace name, and this allows multiple `DbConnection`-derived classes to share the `Dispose()` implementation.

Comment: Thanks. I spotted it was partial but as couldn't find another definition, assumed there wasn't. Hadn't considered the option of them being generated at build time.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the `Dispose()` method doesn't have a specific implementation in `SqlConnection`, and just inherits from [Component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3cc9y48w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

You can check the [SqlConnection documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which confirms that.

Answer (score -1):

Only classes that implements IDisposable interface can have the Dispose (Unless you write yourown) method.

SqlConnection class has the Dispose method because it's inherit's Component

Source: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

And you can find more about IDisposable interface [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)